# Use requests library in Python to get data from Microsoft Academic Knowledge REST API

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am new to using the requests library and APIs. I would like to use [Microsoft's Academic REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-evaluate-method) and put the results in a Pandas DataFrame. What I have so far is this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?'
params = {
    "expr":"Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')",
    "count":2,
    "attributes":"Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId",
}
r = requests.post(url, params=params)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

I have a primary key, not sure where to put that. Thanks.

Comment: I guess with _primary key_ you mean a subscription key, yes?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [REST specification](https://msr-apis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/academic-search-api/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03) is a bit hidden, so you need to submit the key as part of the request header:

```
import requests

subscription_key = 'XXX'

url = 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate'
params = {
    "expr": "Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')",
    "count": 2,
    "attributes": "Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId"
}
headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}

r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Hmm this ends up giving HTTP Status 500 (internal service error). In Python, I get the error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)." Any idea why (yes, I did replace the subscription key with a valid key)? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use `GET evaluate` or `POST evaluate` (see link posted in answer)? Because title says GET and method says POST. For `POST` we might need to change the body and header.content-type

Comment: Yes, looks like `GET evaluate` is what I'm looking for. Thank you.